# Adding sub bullet list for pdf_document rmarkdown file

Tags: r-markdown

I'm trying to create an ordered list with sub bullet in an rmarkdown file but anytime i knitr to a pdf, the sub bullet list does not work, it only works when I knitr to html. I used the code below:

```
Food list
----------

* Rice

* Vegetables

  * Tomatoes
  
  * Carrot
  
  * Cabbage
  
------------
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested list (i.e. a bullet list in this example) in a main list (i.e. an ordered list in this example) should be indented four spaces, as shown below.

By the way, you have to use [the proper Pandoc notation for an ordered list](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#ordered-lists) (i.e. `1.` ) to create an ordered list.

````
---
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default
---

Food list
---------

1. Rice
1. Vegetables
    * Tomatoes
    * Carrot
    * Cabbage
1. Fish  

```{r sessionInfo}
rmarkdown::pandoc_version()  # 2.19.2 in my environment
packageVersion("knitr")      # 1.39 in my environment
packageVersion("rmarkdown")  # 2.14 in my environment
```
````

## HTML output

[image]

## PDF output

[image]